# FFMPEG -rc_override option not working

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to use -rc_override option for FFMPEG. However, i do not see any change in the frame

I have tried 2 command mentioned below

ffmpeg  -i abp1.mp4  -b:v 154k -rc_override:v 6336,6436,-48    -vstats_file stats.txt -c:v libx265 -c:a copy abp1_compress_154.mp4

ffmpeg  -i abp1.mp4  -b:v 154k -rc_override:v 6336,6436,1    -vstats_file stats.txt -c:v libx265 -c:a copy abp1_compress_154.mp4

Please let me know if there is any issue with this command

Answer (score 0):

`-rc_override` is an old option confined to the internal MPEG-1/2 encoders.

For x265, use [zones](http://x265.readthedocs.io/en/default/cli.html#cmdoption-zones).

```
ffmpeg -i abp1.mp4 -c:v libx265 -b:v 154k -x265-params "zones=6336,6436,b=1.5"
       -vstats_file stats.txt -c:a copy abp1_compress_154.mp4
```

`b` here indicates the bitrate multiplier.

Comment: I tried following 2 command for comparison                                          ffmpeg -i abp1.mp4 -c:v libx265 -b:v 154k -x265-params "zones=6336,6436,b=1.5"
       -vstats_file stats.txt -c:a copy abp1_compress_154.mp4                                                                                ffmpeg -i abp1.mp4 -c:v libx265 -b:v 154k        -vstats_file stats1.txt -c:a copy abp1_compress_154.mp4...... However, there was no difference  in the stats file. Any other parameter which i should include

Comment: I tried for another zone i.e. from 1 to 100 frames and i could see the change.  I am trying to ensure that SSIM comparison between 2 videos should not drop below 0.98.  The SSIM for 1 to 100 has an improvement. But the same i could not do while using zone 6336,6436. SSIM for 6336 to 6446 continue to be around 0.95 to 0.96

Comment: But does the vstats file show a change in the compressed frame size for those frames?

Comment: 1 to 100 shows a difference in the compressed frame size. However, there is no difference from 6336 to 6446

Comment: Frame sizes are **identical** to the no-zone output?

Comment: This is my observation 1) If i run the command "ffmpeg -i abp1.mp4 -c:v libx265 -b:v 154k -x265-params zones="1,100,b=3" -vstats_file stats2.txt -c:a copy abp1_compress_154.mp4". There is change in the frame size. SSIM improves for frame 1 - 100. This changes the frame size of non zone also (2) If i run command "ffmpeg -i abp1.mp4 -c:v libx265 -b:v 154k -x265-params zones="6336,6436,b=3" -vstats_file stats2.txt -c:a copy abp1_compress_154.mp4". There is no change in frame size of zone and non zone. SSIM does not improve for zone 6336 to 6436

Comment: What's the average bitrate of the output file (with zone applied)?

Comment: Average bit rate with zone=1,100 changes. However, there is no change for  zone=6336,6436

Comment: I wanted to know the avg bitrate of the output. Anyway, I did a test. x265 modulates the q factor. This has an expect if the multiplier is high enough. Check with a much higher `b` value and then lower it till size/SSIM is acceptable.

Comment: Can you let me know the source code file name which i can refer to check the expect for high multiplier?

Comment: i wanted to update the source code in such a way that it will adopt bit rate with ssim = 0.98

Comment: In `source/ratecontrol.cpp`, in fn `RateControl::rateEstimateQscale`, starting on ln 1912 of current HEAD of repo.

Comment: I tried with libx264 and it seems to be having the right behaviour "ffmpeg  -i video.mp4  -vstats_file video.txt -c:v libx264 -b:v 354k -b:a 60K -x264-params zones="5226,5236,b=10"  -c:a copy video_compress.mp4". However, it seems 264 produce approx. 5% additional size

Comment: I think the issue is with frame comparison. It looks like FFMPEG has changed the number of frames. On my windows machines when i check properties of file then it gives 29 frames/second for original video and 30 frames/second for compressed video. Hence, SSIM comparison may not be accurate. How can i ensure that frame rate is not changed by FFMPEG?

Comment: Add `-vsync vfr`

Comment: Thanks... It looks like there is some issue with ssim. I used the command ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vstats_file video.txt -c:v libx264 -b:v 254k -b:a copy -x264-params zones="5226,5236,b=10/4474,4502,b=10" video_compress.mp4 . Frame size have increased, but ssim does not improve at all. Looking at the video i do not see any difference around the region from 4474 to 4502. Any thoughts?

Comment: Instead of bitrate multiplier, apply q e.g. `q=10`

Comment: The issue seems to be with the frame synch up between original and compressed video. I extract an image of the frame which was showing ssim=0.64 i.e. extract frame number 3104 from original and compressed video. It looks like there is an offset of 1 - 2 frames between the 2 videos. I tried -vync vfr & -vsync passthrough. However, the difference in the offset of t he frame is not going. I am still getting different image for frame# 3104

Comment: How are using vsync (command) and how are you extracting frames?

Comment: Command for vsync: ffmpeg -i keysight.mp4 -c:v libx264 -b:v 254k  -vsync vfr -vstats_file stats.txt -c:a copy keysight_compress.mp4

Comment: Command to extract frame# 3109: ffmpeg -i keysight.mp4 -vf select=gte(n\,3108) -vframes 1 -f image2 keysight-%03d.jpeg

Comment: Does the conversion cmd console show any entries for dup or drop in progress readout?

Comment: Are you visually comparing input and output frames (for matching)?

Comment: i am using ssim for comparison logs. Visual comparison where ssim = .64. i.e frame number 3109

Comment: Share the input.